# Can pass IMU data to ARCore?

Tags: arcore

I'd like to pass video and IMU data from the other HW to Galaxy8.
Galaxy8 ARCore will use these external data for AR instead phone's data.
Is there special way to pass external data to Galaxy8 for AR?

Thanks

Comment: This is an “I want a pony” question and it’s too broad to give a specific technical answer, making it off-topic here on Stack Overflow. You’ll need to attempt to solve this problem and show your code so we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level as well as to demonstrate your commitment to solving this problem.

Comment: Does the ARCore SDK allow to configure the video source and IMU Data as the input for processing to others than the embedded cameras and IMU? 
I can extract Video and IMU data from exteranl HW and to pass that to Galaxy8. But threre is problem to use that data from Galaxy8 ARCore.

Comment: Unless you're at the coding stage this question is off-topic on Stack Overflow.